# Instagram API - Receiving public_content in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api, endpoints

I am developing an app that uses the Instagram API. While in sandbox mode, it seems as though IG does not allow you to use any endpoint that requires the 'public_content' scope. That being said, when I submit the app for approval and request the 'public_content' permission to be approved, it is always returning back rejected (tried 4 times now).

My question is this:

1. Is there a way to make requests using 'public_content' scope while in sandbox mode? If not, how they expect to ever approve 'public_content' if my video screencast cannot show me using that permission? How do I get around this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another user to the sandbox. You can only access that users media via API if you have `public_content` permission.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks very, very helpful! I added a few users to sandbox and now I am geting public content via tag request. Make sense come to think about it. Thanks a lot!